# numeric array sort()

Tags: javascript

Is this part from the book "Learning PHP, MySql and Javascript by. Robin Nixon" wrong?

```
numbers = [7, 23, 6, 74];

numbers.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});
```

output is 6,7,23,74

The book says:

> If the anonymous function inside sort() returns a value greater than zero, the sort assumes **a** comes before **b**.
>
> If the anonymous function inside sort() return a value less than zero, the sort assumes **b** comes before **a**.
>
> The sort runs this function across all the values in the array to determine their order.

is this wrong? Because....

`a` here is `7`
`b` here is `23`

`7 - 23 = -16` // a number less than zero. Book says it should b comes before a.

so the final output should be `74, 23, 7, 6`

Comment: No, it's right: http://jsfiddle.net/cjD3v/

Comment: You know, you could just: _try it out_. Like in the above jsfiddle

Comment: but the explanation from the book is that wrong??

Comment: Currently the numbers are being sorted from smallest to largest. What you think the final output should be is largest to smallest. It's an easy tweak to make it decrement.

Comment: Yes, the explanation in the book is wrong.

Comment: im just asking if the explanation from the book is wrong i know the output is 6,7,23,74

Comment: Thats what im asking so the explanation from the book is wrong. Thanks guys.

Comment: What are we discussing here? Is book right or wrong? The fact is your script,not a book.

Comment: +1 because I support reading books.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Nobody argues,that reading books is good thing, but here, the fact is script shows other results,than book says.So you must believe in script,and not in book.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that it is wrong. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> If compareFunction(a, b) is less than 0, sort a to a lower index than b.

("Lower index" in this case would mean that a comes before b)

Answer (score 2):

The output is correct, but the explanation is not. If the method returns < 0, a comes before b.