# Sort array and specify starting position

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Using Javascript, I want to sort an array of integer, but instead of starting at 0, I would like to be able to specify the first item in the array. For example, using this array as a starting point:

```
var array = [4, 0, 1, 2, 5, 8, 7, 3, 6];
```

If I want to re-order but start at 3, with the end result:

```
var array = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2];
```

Start at 8 would look like this:

```
var array = [8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
```

Start at 0 would look like this (default sort):

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
```

Any idea how I can do this?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? An ordering does not "start" somewhere. Do you want to sort the array and then rotate it until the `2` is up front?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {
   return (a<2) - (b<2) || a - b;
});
```

The first condition returns `1` or `-1` depending on whether `a` or `b` are smaller than `2`, or `0` if both are on the same "side" of `2`, in which case the second ([standard number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367697/numeric-array-sort)) comparison takes place.

Comment: Could you explain what `(a<2)` or `(b<2)` would return when `a` or `b` is e.g. 5? At first I thought it would return `true` or `false` but that wouldn't make sense as you're calculating with the returned value afterwards? Thanks!

Comment: @codezombie: You can calculate with the booleans, they will be casted to `0`/`1` when being subtracted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Didn't know that so far! :-) But if `(a<2)` and `(b<2)` are both true, it would be `0 - 0` which yields `0` and equals `true`, wouldn't it? In that case, why is the second statement used instead of returning `true`? @Bergi

Comment: `0` evaluates to `false` in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
var array = [3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 5];

var startNumber = 2;
var test = array.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(b < startNumber) {
        return -1;
    } else if(a < startNumber) {
        return 1;
    } else {
       return a - b;
    }
});

// test == [2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Notice that this will leave `0` and `1` unsorted

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, because in your original array `0` and `1` are already sorted.
Assuming that you want to sort the entire array and then shift the array to put first two elements to the end, you can use this code:

```
var array = [3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 5];
array = array.sort();
i = array.indexOf(2);
move = array.splice(0, i);
array.splice(array.length, 0, move);
alert(array);
```

Demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uMgL9/).