# Sort both values in a multidimensional

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Im wokring on a bit of functionality that works a lot with multidimensional arrays. What I would like to do is sort by the first value then sort by the second value while keeping the first value sorted. See example:

```
arrayToSort = [[1,5],[1,3],[1,2],[1,6],[2,6],[1,9],[1,11]];

I would like to sort this so it returns

[[1,2],[1,3],[1,5],[1,6],[1,9],[1,11],[2,6]];
```

I have created* a function to sort the array by the first value using the function below but im unsure how exactly i can achieve the above.

```
function sortOne(cards){
    arr = cards.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a[0] > b[0];
    });
    return arr;
}
```

*source: [How to sort 2 dimensional array by column value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096872/how-to-sort-2-dimensional-array-by-column-value/16096900#16096900)

Comment: Notice that your current comparison function is extremely inconsistent, it never returns a negative value.

Comment: @Bergi My array will never contain negative values so this is fine.

Comment: @GlenRobson: No, it's not about the values. If `a` is smaller than `b`, then the comparison must return a negative value (`-1`). Check [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)!

Comment: @Bergi I didnt write this code you may want to take it up with the person that did: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16096900/1531541

Comment: @GlenRobson in the question you write "I have created a function to sort the array" and as soon as there is a flaw you "credit" your "source". TT

Comment: @Winchestro I apologise, by created i did not mean i personally wrote that function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort by the first value, then by the second:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[0]-b[0] || a[1]-b[1];
});
```

It's just two ([standard number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367697/numeric-array-sort)) comparisons, linked by the `||` operator which returns the right operand when the first is `0`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23883042/1048572) for a generic comparison function that deals with arrays of arbitrary length, not only tuples.